# how to dismiss a modal viewcontroller in iOS6

Tags: modal-dialog, viewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dismissModalViewControllerAnimated deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445190/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-deprecated)

I have 2 view controllers, one being a game and the second simply being an "About" screen.  When someone goes to the about screen - presented as a modal view controller - how can I have them dismiss the view controller to get back to the first screen?

I can do this with a push segue, but that causes my game to "reload".

THe following code appears to work, but XCode warns that it is deprecated.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

What is the new way to do this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```