# using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Tags: xcode, objective-c-blocks

Some code I am using uses the deprecated method `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`. The docs say to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` now. I am unsure about the `completion:` part. In my case should the completion be `nil` or `NULL` or what?

Original code is as follows.

```
- (void)didFinishWithCamera
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if ([self.capturedImages count] > 0)
    {
        if ([self.capturedImages count] == 1)
        {
            // we took a single shot
            [self.imageView setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
        else
        {
            // we took multiple shots, use the list of images for animation
            self.imageView.animationImages = self.capturedImages;

            if (self.capturedImages.count > 0)
                // we are done with the image list until next time
                [self.capturedImages removeAllObjects];

            self.imageView.animationDuration = 5.0;    // show each captured photo for 5 seconds
            self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;   // animate forever (show all photos)
            [self.imageView startAnimating];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about completion, then provide an empty block:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES
                              completion:^(void){}];
```

Comment: So nil isn't okay? I thought a nil completion is fine.

Comment: @WarrenP Actually, `nil` does appear to be OK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445190/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-deprecated

Comment: In which case, not emitting an empty completion would be preferable, and nil would always and everywhere be better. Oh and less typing of punctuation characters.