# UIImagePickerController - [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil]; Error

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been trying this for the past 2 days and I am not able to figure out the answer. I have searched all over and I haven't found the answer.

**The question is** I have a button which brings up the camera in my app(to take photos only). The camera opens up, but when i take a picture and click on "USE"[(which is displayed at the bottom right)](http://www.instructables.com/files/deriv/FAM/KM3W/HAVGJY15/FAMKM3WHAVGJY15.LARGE.jpg) its crashing. Also, when the camera opens up, before taking a picture when I click ["Cancel"](http://www.instructables.com/files/deriv/FXZ/TSCA/HBFFJF25/FXZTSCAHBFFJF25.LARGE.jpg) it again crashes.

I tried using breakpoints and found out that, When I click on the "USE" button, it crashes in this line

`[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil]`

I'm testing it in my iPad (iOS6).

Here is the **Button Code** here :

```
-(IBAction)getAlbum:(id)sender {

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        NSArray *media = [UIImagePickerController
                          availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

        if ([media containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage] == YES) {
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            //picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
            [picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]];

            picker.delegate = self;
            //[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]; //Since [Modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445190/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-deprecated) has been removed
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:Nil];
            //[picker release];

        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unsupported!"
                                                            message:@"Camera does not support photo capturing."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unavailable!"
                                                        message:@"This device does not have a camera."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }


}
```

**imagePickerController Method here:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"Media Info: %@", info);
    NSString *mediaType = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *photoTaken = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        //Save Photo to library only if it wasnt already saved i.e. its just been taken
        if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photoTaken, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }


        selectedLogoImg.image=photoTaken; //selectedLogoImg is the imageView
        [self.clipartItemView addSubview:selectedLogoImg]; // To detect touch and move it I place it as a subview of self.clipartItemView
    }

    //[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil]
    //[picker release];
    //[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
      //  NSLog(@"Dismiss completed");
    //}];
}
```

**didFinishSavingWithError Code Here:**

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    //NSLog(@"Image:%@", image);
    if (error) {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                           message:[error localizedDescription]
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

**imagePickerControllerDidCancel Code Here:**

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    //[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    /*[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:cardGalleryView];
    }];*/
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send the dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: message to the view controller, not the picker. Try:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The above method is only for iOS 6. You need to use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` for iOS 5 and below.

Take a look at the description of the method in the documentation:

> Dismisses the view controller that was presented by the receiver.
>
> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to
>   the presenting view controller

Comment: Should i do that in imagePickerControllerDidCancel or imagePickerController Method ?

Comment: @Vikr in every line where you are trying to dismiss the picker, basically every occurrence of `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];` in your existing code.

Comment: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated in ios6 and they suggest to use dismissViewControllerAnimated ?

Comment: @Vikr no, they suggest to use  dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, with the difference of newly added completion method.

Comment: You want me to use [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; - like you suggested or [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

Comment: @Vikr maybe you can try both first and see what you find. :)

Comment: its crashing when i try with my original code, I cant use what you have suggested - [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; since this is not valid in iOS6. When i try [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil]; im getting this error - *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30482/discussion-between-verbumdei-and-vikr)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to your `UIImagePickerController *picker` object . ViewController isn't able to identify your picker object reference out of the `getAlbum` method scope.

1.> you can create `UIImagePickerController` object in your `.h` file

```
 @interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{

   UIImagePickerController *picker;
   UIPopoverController *popover;
}
```

and in `.m` file you just use it inside `getAlbum` `IBAction` method

```
-(IBAction)getAlbum:(id)sender {

if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    NSArray *media = [UIImagePickerController
                      availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    if ([media containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage] == YES) {

         UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
         if ([popover isPopoverVisible])
         {
              [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
              popover=nil;
         }
         picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
         picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
         [picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]];
         picker.delegate = self;

        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(btn.frame.size.width,btn.frame.size.height/2,1,1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unsupported!"
                                                        message:@"Camera does not support photo capturing."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

 }
 else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unavailable!"
                                                    message:@"This device does not have a camera."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
 }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)myimage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    myimage = [myimage fixOrientation];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

I hope it helps you to better understand.

Comment: Its crashing as usual. I'm using iOS6 in my iPad and I cant use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated. I can only use  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil]; which is also returning error

Comment: Hi Vikr, Please have a look on my updated code and use didFinishPickingImage: instead of didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: . If you are using ipad then picker would work with UIPopoverController so if any UIPopoverController obeject is avaliable then use  [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; for it.

Comment: Hi Vikr, 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'. This is rule by apple otherwise your app will reject in appstore so for ipad implement UIImagePickerController via UIPopoverController

Comment: Yes, I'm testing my app in a iPad.. Actually ViewWillAppear is playing the spoil sport. If i comment it, the above code is working. But then, other work called in viewwillappear seems to be not working.

Comment: you should apply UIPopoverController inside getAlbum for picking image from camera. With out an UIPopoverController in an ipad app , Apple reject your application under review period so try to apply it with UIPopoverController. I m updating my code with your getAlbum method . Use it and apply

Comment: My original code is working. I just had to set a BOOL for viewWillAppear and use it in my existing code.