# presentModalViewController:animated is deprecated

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, upgrade

I am getting a warning in XCode:

```
'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

on this line of code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:initialSettingsVC animated:YES];
```

I tried to replace it as suggested in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) with:

```
[self presentModalViewController:initialSettingsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I now get an error in XCode:

> No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector
> 'presentModalViewController:animated:completion:'

Any ideas?

Comment: You have misspelled the method.  It's `presentViewController:animated:completion`.  Remove the 'Modal'.

Comment: @bbarnhart You are right. This is the solution.

Answer (score 11):

Use following........

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
    [self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];
}
```

i found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445190/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-deprecated)

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
[self presentModalViewController:initialSettingsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To

```
[self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: As of ios 10, this will not do a modal presentation.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the following

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent 
                      animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
```

settting `UIModalPresentationStyle` and `UIModalTransitionStyle` for `viewController` in order to get the modal animation /presentation you're looking for