# Suppress `deprecated` warnings in Xcode

Tags: xcode

`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is deprecated:first deprecated in `iOS` 6.0

- My deployment target is 6.1 and `Xcode` is 5.1.
- I want to remove  this warning for 6.1 simulator.Is that Possible?????
- If I will run that by selection in ios 5.1 then no warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445190/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-deprecated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing deprecated warnings in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622017/suppressing-deprecated-warnings-in-xcode)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I am correct, you simply want to suppress the warnings.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```

This is simply to suppress the warnings. In release builds, you should not use any deprecated functions.

EDIT: To suppress specific code that invokes warnings, use :

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: better replace the deprecated code with the new one instead of supressing, simply replace the line with: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];. This is the better option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is there any solution to hide warnings for that particular warnings.I don't want to supress all the warnings in that VC.

Comment: See updated code.
Also, unless your deployment target < 5.0, it's suggested to use the newer methods. They are available since iOS 5.x

Comment: Thanks  n00bProgrammer :)

Comment: Excellent! I've been looking for this forever.

Comment: Apps are not rejected for using deprecated methods?! If they were 75% of all Apps out there would be ejected from the store ;)

Comment: Yes, if it won't make your app crash, it will be never rejected!

Comment: Others have mentioned it, but need to mention it again - APPLE WILL NOT REJECT AN APP THAT USES DEPRECATED METHODS.

Comment: This works well for me. Because I am using Api that was deprecated in iOS9. But the newer API does not work with iOS 9. So there is no other solution but to suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

@n00bProgrammer thanks for your answer.

For those of us who still have code that supports earlier versions of iOS, the way I handle such old code is to wrap the older code in a version macro test as well as to suppress the compiler warnings that result.

*Note that sometimes a deprecated item generates an **implicit conversion warning** that needs to be suppressed using "-Wconversion".*

```
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
        #pragma clang diagnostic push
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
        [controlCenter.label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        #pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        [controlCenter.label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    }
```

You can find the version checker for older Objective-C code here: [SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7848772/1148240)

You can find the version checker for new Swift and Objective-C code here: [Swift and Objective-C version check past iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339787/1148240)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
[self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

use thus the following code it works perfect

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Tested and working fine.

:)