# Supressing specific deprecated messages

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have this code that is supposed to run on iOS 6 and up. Apple deprecated some stuff on iOS 7 and at some point I have to have code like this:

```
if (isIOS7) 
   doItTheNewWay
else
   doItTheOldWay
```

the problem is that doItTheOldWay is deprecated on iOS7 and I see an error telling me that it was deprecated on iOS 7.

How do I get rid of this error in particular?

The line in the example is this:

```
    titleSize = [self.title sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constrainedSize];
```

Comment: Do you want to fix this particular deprecicate warning or do you want to suppress all of theses warning messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, it works for me:

```
if (isIOS7)
    //doItTheNewWay
else
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    //doItTheOldWay
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Credit goes [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1902083/1262634).

Answer (score 0):

In `Xcode` set `Deprecated Functions` to `No`.

[image: Deprecated]

Comment: thanks but your solution will turn off all deprecated messages and I have asked for a specific one. See null answer, much better. Thanks anyway.